# Преобразовать строку в исполняемый код

Tags: c++, qt

В функцию из базы прилетает `QList<QVariant>` который состоит из `QString`,
которые содержат название `ui` элементов и соответственно настроек.

Предположим: прилетело `checkBox`,`setChecked(true)`.

Вопрос №1: Как обернуть эти строки, чтоб получить 
`ui->checkBox->setChecked(true);`

Мне как начинающему, это решение кажется костыльным, но и городить
кучу `if` не мене.

Вопрос №2: Как выполнить данную задачу более изящно?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы рассматривали использование для этого скриптовых языков типа Lua?

Comment: То, что вы хотите называется рефлексией, я правда не знаю можно ли тут на ютюб сслыки кидать, но вот вам https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oBgonj_E7Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На форме размещены два чекбокса: checkBox, checkBox_2

```
QWidget *checkBox1 = findChild<QWidget*>("checkBox");
checkBox1->setProperty("checked", true);

QWidget *checkBox2 = findChild<QWidget*>("checkBox_2");
checkBox2->setProperty("checked", true);
```

название виджетов, название и значение устанавливаемых свойств можно использовать из `QList<QVariant>` из базы

Answer (score 0):

Как более гибкое решение, попробуйте посмотреть в сторону `QJSEngine`, он позволяет исполнить скриптовый код внутри вашего приложения.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtjavascript.html